# using functional interfaces in java

Tags: java, function, predicate, consumer, functional-interface

I have `ProductSettings` and `ProductType`. Product settings determine whether product types are enabled or not.

```
ProductSettings productSettings = new ProductSettings()
            .setIsTreasuryInfoEnabled(true)
            .setIsTreasurySwiftInfoEnabled(true)
            .setIsTreasuryExecutionControlEnabled(true)
            .setIsAcceptEnabled(true);

public enum ProductType {
INFO,
INFOSWIFT,
BUDGETCONTROL,
ACCEPT,
DIRECTACCOUNTCONTROL
```

how can i fill the `enabledProductTypes` set using functional interfaces and vs task - enable settings by having product types?

```
Set<ProductType> enabledProductTypes = EnumSet.noneOf(ProductType.class);
```

I created map

```
static Map<ProductType, Predicate<ProductSettings>> mapGetter = new HashMap<>();

static Map<ProductType, BiConsumer<ProductSettings, Boolean>> mapSetter = new HashMap<>();
```

and filled out `mapGetter`  with Predicate like this:

```
mapGetter.put(ProductType.ACCEPT, ProductSettings::getIsAcceptEnabled);


mapGetter.put(ProductType.INFO,ProductSettings::getIsTreasuryInfoEnabled);
```

and filled out `mapSetter` with BiConsumer like this:

```
mapSetter.put(ProductType.ACCEPT, ProductSettings::setIsAcceptEnabled);

mapSetter.put(ProductType.INFO, ProductSettings::setIsTreasuryInfoEnabled);
```

but how to use it I can't understand.
I guess i shoul iterate by my map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should iterate through your Maps.

```
ProductSettings settings = /* ... */;

Set<ProductType> enabledProductTypes = EnumSet.noneOf(ProductType.class);

for (Map.Entry<ProductType, Predicate<ProductSettings>> entry : mapGetter) {
    ProductType type = entry.getKey();
    Predicate<ProductSettings> enabled = entry.getValue();

    if (enabled.test(settings)) {
        enabledProductTypes.add(type);
    }
}
```

And:

```
ProductSettings settings = /* ... */;
Set<ProductType> enabledProductTypes = /* ... */

for (Map.Entry<ProductType, BiConsumer<ProductSettings, Boolean>> entry : mapSetter) {
    ProductType type = entry.getKey();
    BiConsumer<ProductSettings, Boolean>> setter = entry.getValue();

    setter.accept(settings, enabledProductTypes.contains(type));
}
```